# Heap corruption detected error when attempting to free pointer

Tags: memory-management, c++-cli

I'm pretty new to C++ and have run into a problem which I have not been able to solve. I'm trying to convert a System::String to a wchar_t pointer that I can keep for longer than the scope of the function. Once I'm finished with it, I want to clean it up properly. Here is my code:

```
static wchar_t* g_msg;

void TestConvert()
{
    pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wchptr = PtrToStringChars("Test");
    g_msg = (wchar_t*)realloc(g_msg, wcslen(wchptr) + 1);
    wcscpy(g_msg, wchptr);

    free (g_msg); // Will be called from a different method
}
```

When the free is called, I'm getting "HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#137) at 0x02198F90."

Why would I be getting this error?

Andrew L

Comment: Did you allocate the memory with malloc() before the call to realloc()?

Comment: @Timo - It doesn't matter. "If memblock is NULL, realloc behaves the same way as malloc and allocates a new block of size bytes" from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbebcx7d.aspx

Comment: Compare the pointers after the allocation and before the release. BTW, do you have to resort to C memory management? Why not `new`/`delete`?

Comment: `System.String` is not C++. Changed tag to "C++/CLI" to reflect the language you're actually using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the you're allocating too small memory block for the string. Each character takes 2 bytes (in MSVC) because it's a wide string:

```
g_msg = (wchar_t*)realloc(g_msg, (wcslen(wchptr) + 1)*sizeof(wchar_t));
```

Comment: Actually, it's more than that. `wcslen` returns the length in characters, but malloc expects bytes. It should be `(wcslen(wchptr) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t)`. Also note that `wcslen` can return incorrect results when dealing with `System.String`, because `System.String` can contain embedded nulls, while plain C strings cannot.

Comment: Hope it's correct now. I never use realloc or wchar_t myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

System::String is a managed string class, not a C++ string class. You need to convert to a std::wstring, which manages it's own memory, not a const wchar_t*.

Comment: Using std::wstring is not an option. I have to convert my System::String to a wchar_t*.